# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: images.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to learn how to fetch data from jsonplaceholder api using axios. I tried to fetch images from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/v1/photos and map it to an img element but I'm getting "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: images.map is not a function" error. How can I solve this error??

Here is my code [image]

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  const getData = async () => {
    const { data: images } = await axios(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos"
    );
    setImages({ images });
    console.log(images);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Populate with imagse from jsonplaceholder
      {images.map((image) => {
        return <img src={image.thumbnailUrl} alt={image.title} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The solutions given work in codeSandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-json-server-9g7wo?file=/src/VideoCard.js But in the real app is still giving me "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function" error

Comment: try changing {images.map((image) => to {images && images.map((image) =>  , because here what is happening is before your axios request is processed and images array is populated the map function is being called when the array is empty.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Now I'm getting "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function" error

Comment: can you tell me the version of react you are using?

Comment: The version of react I'm using is 17.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this:

```
setImages({ images });
```

you are setting the `images` variable to be an object which has one property, `images`, which is an array, kind of like this:

```
const imagesForNextRender = {
  images: [
    /* image data */
  ]
};
```

But you can't `.map` that. Either extract the `images` property first (not recommended):

```
images.images.map(
```

or, more sensibly, call `setImages` with the array itself, rather than wrapping it in an object:

```
const result = await axios("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos");
setImages(result.data);
```

Comment: thanks for the replay. I tried your method but got "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function" error now.

Comment: What line does that occur at?

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. I have added a screen shot of the error that I'm getting.

Comment: It sounds like `axios` isn't a function in your code, and that you aren't importing it properly..? Make sure you're doing `import axios from "axios";`

Comment: I really really appreciate your help. It turns out that was the problem. I auto imported axios and for some reason it was imported { axios } from 'axios'. That was the cause of the error. Again thanks for your help and time